# Graphviz crashes when drawing chord network using DOT

Tags: graphviz

I used Graphviz for quite some time and never had any problem. I was trying to draw a chord network like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Chord_network.png).

I only used 8 nodes. My code is like this:

```
digraph g
{

layout=circo

0 -> 1;
0 -> 2;
0 -> 4;

1 -> 2;
1 -> 3;
1 -> 5;

2 -> 3;
2 -> 4;
2 -> 6;

3 -> 4;
3 -> 5;
3 -> 7;

4 -> 5;
4 -> 6;
4 -> 0;

5 -> 6;
5 -> 7;
5 -> 1;

6 -> 7;
6 -> 0;
6 -> 2;

7 -> 0;
7 -> 1;
7 -> 3;

}
```

When running this, it crashes to desktop. Interestingly, if I remove the last 6 statements, it does not crash and gives the correct output.

I tried reinstalling and the problem persists. I'm using Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: What version of graphviz are you using? What command line? Your graph works fine on win7 64bit with 2.29.20120504.

Comment: Same for me, it works like a charm under Debian using xdot and version 2.26.3 of graphviz. It must be a version problem.

Comment: I am using version 2.34.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think that it is the particular version/OS combination. I just tried it on version 2.36.0 on Mac OS X, and it works fine[image: Output from dot program run on the input data]